# how to bind parameters in sqlsrv without using of PDO

Tags: php, sqlsrv

In MySQL we used the mysqli_stmt_bind_param to bind parameters.
What should I use to bind parameters in sqlsrv?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.[user] WHERE username = ? and password = ?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $params);
if($stmt === false){
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

How can I bind this parameters? This is a php file and I need to bind them without pdo.

Comment: Check the manual and come back here with what you've attempted

Answer (score 1):

You don't explicitly bind the parameters by using another function, you do it when preparing the statement.

See the example from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php).

```
$sql = "UPDATE Table_1
        SET OrderQty = ?
        WHERE SalesOrderID = ?";

// Initialize parameters and prepare the statement. 
// Variables $qty and $id are bound to the statement, $stmt.
$qty = 0; $id = 0;
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql, array( &$qty, &$id));
if( !$stmt ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Set up the SalesOrderDetailID and OrderQty information. 
// This array maps the order ID to order quantity in key=>value pairs.
$orders = array( 1=>10, 2=>20, 3=>30);

// Execute the statement for each order.
foreach( $orders as $id => $qty) {
    // Because $id and $qty are bound to $stmt1, their updated
    // values are used with each execution of the statement. 
    if( sqlsrv_execute( $stmt ) === false ) {
          die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
}
```